# Error Message - Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default

Tags: r, regression

I am recoding categorical variables into binary outcomes for a logistic regression experiment. (seeing how select independent variables impact self reported health satisfaction in Britain)

Upon recoding using dplyr I get the error message - Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default

Please refer to the below code and if anybody could suggest an lteration to my code to eliminate Na's in my new binary output it would be appreciated

```
projectdata$c_employ <- recode_factor(projectdata$c_employ,"no"=0, "yes"=1)
summary(projectdata$c_employ)
```

output:

```
    0     1  NA's 
20514 25381     8
```

(How do I change the above code to get rid of NA variables that I don't want in my binary output)

Comment: NA variables? Do you mean cases that have NA for that variable? If so, `projectdata[!is.na(projectdata$c_employ), ]`

Comment: Or, the tidyverse way: `tidyr::drop_na(projectdata, c_employ)`.